# use 'grep' command the way column names would be preserved

Tags: linux, bash

I paid attention that 'grep' command removes the column names.
I need to customize the output of processes according to the following command:

```
ps -ef | egrep "java|mysql" | awk {'print $1, $2, $8'}
```

Regular 'ps' (or even with the 'awk') have column names: UID, PID, etc...
However, when i add 'grep' the column names gone.
Ideally i must have the 'ps' output that displays 4 columns - PID, user name, CMD, and memory usage.
How do i get it preserving the column names.

Comment: What's about `top -p$pid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `grep` command will strip the headers because they do not match. Just use `awk` and match on the first row condition in addition to the search patterns.

```
ps -ef |  awk 'NR==1{print $1,$2,$8} /java|mysql/{print $1, $2, $8}'
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but unfortunately not completely for my need. I'm trying to use `ps -aux | awk 'NR==1{print $1,$2,$8} /java|mysql/{print $1, $2, $8}'` to have the memory usage. The problem is that i must monitor only the processes launched from '/opt' directory, and here 'grep' trims the headers.
 @merlin2011 - Is there any way to filter except 'grep'?

Comment: I'm not clear on what your question has to do with using or not using grep.  My answer does not use grep.

Comment: Yes, it serves my need, but partially. I would like to filter the processes from certain directory only:
`ps -aux |  awk 'NR==1{print $2,$1,$4,$3,$11} /java|mysql/{print $2,$1,$4,$3,$11}'`
Where $11 is the command itself (header COMMAND). In other conditions i would filter it with `| grep /opt`, but in case of your solution it will break the headers. Do you have an idea how to filter by directory without a grep?

Comment: forgot to tag - @merlin2011

Comment: Hi @merlin2011,
I modified a bit your solution, and now it suits my needs for 100%. It looks like :
`ps -aux | awk 'NR==1{print $2,$1,$4,$3,$11} /java|mysql/{print $2,$1,$4,$3,$11}' | sed -e '1b' -e '/opt/!d'`

Comment: Probably cleaner to write `NR==1 || /java|mysql/ { print ...`

Answer (score 0):

Use the power of `bash`.

```
$ cat pid_top.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter String:"
read p

top -n 1 -b -p $(ps -e | grep $p | awk '{print $1}') | tail -n 2
```

Don't forget `chmod +x pid_top.sh`

Make an alias or run the script by name, enter a string, e.g. for firefox just *fire* an you will have and output like this:

```
$ ./p*
Enter String:
fire
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     ZEIT+ BEFEHL
2983 bang      20   0 1605624 600168 108940 S   0,0 15,1  40:28.10 firefox
```

Comment: Hi @John,
Thanks for your comment. However your suggestion seems to be more compatible with desktops, and not hardened servers. Anyway i tried it with another application and got the following output:
`top -hv | -bcHiOSs -d secs -n max -u|U user -p pid(s) -o field -w [cols]`